# Как лучше организовать работу с FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: c#, .net, события

Имеется 10 сетевых папок. На каждую папку я вешаю свой `FileSystemWatcher`.

Задача уведомить программы, которые используют эти папки и отключить программы.

Программы могут использовать несколько папок, а так же папки могут пересекаться между программами.

Накидал вот такой код:

```
 public class Program
    {
        public string ProgramName { get; set; }
        public string ProgramPath { get; set; }
        HashSet<string> ProgramShares = new HashSet<string>();
        public void TernOffProgram()
        {
        //Какой-то код
        }
    }

     public class Programs
    {
        List<Program> ProgramList = new List<Program>();
        void TernOffPrograms(string sharePath)
        {
            foreach (var program in ProgramList)
            {
                var shareIsMatched = program.programShares.SingleOrDefault(share => share == sharePath) == null;
                if (shareIsMatched)
                {
                     program.TernOffProgram();
                }   
            }
        }
        public void ErrorHadler(object sender, ErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            var watcher = (FileSystemWatcher)sender;
            TernOffPrograms(watcher.Path);
        }
    }
```

Соответственно `ErrorHadler` подписывается на `N` событий от `FileSystemObject`.

Проблема такой реализации в том, что если одновременно упадет несколько сетевых папок, то ввиду того, что каждое событие обрабатывается в отдельном потоке, получится ерунда, например, обращение к одному и тому же объекту `Program` из разных потоков, что чревато какой-то ерундой.

Comment: А почему бы не перевести все события в один поток?

Comment: @VladD, lock добавить?

Comment: Скорее `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` если на WPF, или `Control.Invoke` если на WinForms

Comment: @VladD  я хотел это в службу затолкать. Как будут работать события в 1 поток? Пока одно событие не обработается, другое не наступит? А если во время обработки одного события наступит другое, то оно не потеряется?

Comment: Если всё будет в один поток, то новое событие будет ждать в очереди старое, пока то не отпустит поток, по идее.

Comment: Я бы заюзал Reactive Extensions и представил каждый `FileSystemWatcher` как поток событий, а потом объединил их в один с помощью `Merge`.

Comment: @VladD,@Raider, приведите примеры кода, как бы вы это реализовали, а заодно напишите, чем плох Lock в обработчике, если его добавить.

Comment: На самом деле, непонятна проблема, в вопросе упоминается какой то `project`, которого нет в коде. В чем проблема то, когда из разных потоков дергают ваш класс?

Comment: @Monk, опечатался малость, там Program. Проблема в том, что будет дергаться одна и та же коллекция из разных потоков.

Comment: Хорошо, ещё уточняющий вопрос - класс `Programm` завершает свою работу при вызове метода `off` или нет? Предлагаю принимать в метод папку, обработку сделать thread-safe и не заморачиваться с остальным.

Comment: @Monk, вообще нет. Я планирую добавить включение программ, что бы при возвращении шары их включать.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, при отключении одной любой шары программу надо выключить.

Предлагаю дополнить класс `Program` вот так:

```
private int isEnabled = 0;

public void TernOffProgram()
{
  var old = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isEnabled, 0, 1);
  if (old == 0)
    return;

  //Какой-то код
}
```

На запуске наоборот ставить единицу аналогично, т.к. скорее всего по тому же событию будет запуск у вас.